# How to get a pixel color from Image, in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter

How can I get the pixel color at a specific `(x,y)` coordinate from an Image that I have in my assets folder. I already tried this package : https://pub.dev/packages/image because it has a `getPixel(x,y)` method, but if I try to load a File: `Image image = decodeImage(File('../assets/image.jpg').readAsBytesSync());` ,I get this error: `(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`. And it doesnt matter if its a relative or absolute path, it wont't work.

So I noticed that you have to use `final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.jpg');` to load an Image. And my newest approach was to use the Image package and create an new image: `img.Image myImage = img.Image.fromBytes(width, height, bytes);` But for that I need a list of bytes `List<int>` bytes. And I'm not sure how to get that list? Do I get it from ByteData when loading the image from the assets folder?

So 2 questions: How can I get the pixel color at a specific `(x,y)` from an image. And if thats not possible, how can I get a list of bytes from an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `bytes` from the `ByteData` that you already figured out how to get. Do `data.buffer` to get the `ByteBuffer` and use its `asUint8List` method to get a `List<int>` that you can pass to create an `img.Image` with its `fromBytes` constructor.

You can use the [`getPixel`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/image/Image/getPixel.html) method to get the bytes from a particular pixel.